# CSV headers next to data - Rails Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

So, I'm trying to import a CSV file with RoR that is in the following format:

```
header,data,header,data,header,data
```

An example would be:

```
name,peter,age,12,birthplace,london
name,john,age,30,birthplace,new york
```

After I've imported the file, how can I allocate the header that matches up the database. The order may different every time and some fields may be in the CSV and other fields may not. How would I go about in my Model to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as the following:

```
all_attributes = []
CSV.foreach('path/to/file') do |row|
  attributes = {}
  row.each_with_index do |column, i|
    next if i % 2 != 0 # skip every other column
    attributes[column.to_sym] = row[i+1]
  end
  all_attributes << attributes
end
```

This code relies on the fact that a header is ALWAYS 1 column before the value.

Comment: Okay, got it to work except that it imports the first line twice with your exact code. Any ideas?

Comment: I changed the `CSV.open` to `CSV.foreach` @AdamEsterhuizen (doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-A+Line+at+a+Time)